# Error from setuptools (pkg_resources)

Tags: python, setuptools, pkg-resources

While trying to local install a python rpm (in directory `~/.local/`)

with `python setup.py install --user`

I get the error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 701, in process_distribution
distreq.project_name, distreq.specs, requirement.extras
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

After checking fileeasy_install in line 701, I found out that Requirement class produced the error which is imported from pkg_resources

I found out that inside folder: `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`
there exist:

1. `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py`
2. `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/`

Inside pkg_resources.py class Requirement takes 4 arguments

while class Requirement from

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging  /requirements.py
```

takes 2 arguments

How may I uninstall folder:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/
```

May I just delete its contents?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should upgrade your setuptools:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Also I believe you should backup and remove `pkg_resources.py`, I don't know where the module comes from.